# Replacing a trailing '-' with a leading '-'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I received a csv file (2.6M records) with some values in an hours amount field and a dollars amount field that have a trailing '-' to represent a negative adjustment. I'm trying to figure out a way to move the trailing '-' to a leading '-' so I can set the data type to a numeric value. Replace sounded like a good option however without using wildcards it really isn't as there are thousands of different amounts. Any help would be appreciated. Samples below...
4982.01-
165.48-
0.01-
159.92-
1532.70-
156.38-
766.50-
144.58-

Comment: You could just remove '-' across the entire file? And you'll be able to treat all values as negative values.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following update:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = '-' + SUBSTRING(col, 1, LEN(col) - 1)
WHERE col LIKE '%-';
```

Comment: What if the column value doesn't have a trailing '-' in some rows?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Read my answer closely: `WHERE col LIKE '%-'`

Comment: That sir was genius and worked perfectly! Thank you.